# How to get total count of children of a class containing Dictionary of same type?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a **'Node'** class as follows:

```
public class Node
{
public readonly IDictionary<string, Node> _nodes =
new Dictionary<string, Node>();

public string Path { get; set; }            
}
```

I want to get the total child count of `_nodes` of object of the above class. There can be any level of depths. Let us suppose i create an object as:

```
Node obj = new Node();
```

After iterating, i wish to get total no of `Node`s at all levels of depth. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
foreach (var item in obj._nodes) 
{ 
count += item.Value._nodes.SelectMany(list => list.Value._nodes).Distinct().Count(); 
}
```

---

Comment: Create a method numberOfChildren() that calls the same method on all the `Node` objects in your list and accumulates the sum of those with the length of your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical solution to this problem is to create a [recursive method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3dk2cc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public readonly IDictionary<string, Node> _nodes
        = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

    public int GetTotalChildrenCount()
    {
        return _nodes.Values.Sum(n => n.GetTotalChildrenCount() + 1);
    }
}
```

`+ 1` part is used to count a node itself, apart from the number of its children.

I've omitted the call to the `Distinct` function. It will probably won't work, as your node doesn't have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method overridden.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a tree of nodes. You need to flatten this and then you could count the nodes easily. This is a very nice extension method I googled somewhere ages ago:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> e,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> f)
{
    return e.SelectMany(c => f(c).Flatten(f)).Concat(e);
}
```

When you have that, the rest is easy:

```
var count = new [] {obj}.Flatten(x => x._nodes.Values).Distinct().Count();
```

You may want to override Equals and GetHashCode on Node to make Distinct() work as expected.